# Hacking Preview in Mac OS X

Tags: pdf, preview, customization

For certain PDFs with graphics split over two pages, it is best to view them side-by-side.

Apple's Preview app lets me view two pages side-by-side. This is great!

The only problem is that it's off by one page. For example, if the intended view is the following:

```
 ___________________
| Banner T|ext Here |
|         |         |
|  34     |     35  |
|         |         |
|_________|___ _____|
```

what Preview shows is this:

```
 ___________________
|         | Banner T|
|         |         |
|     33  |  34     |
|         |         |
|_________|___ _____|

<followed by>
 ___________________
|ext Here |         |
|         |         |
|     35  |  36     |
|         |         |
|_________|___ _____|
```

I realize that Apple's choice for Two Page viewing mode is probably optimal for many (most?) situations, but not for mine.

**Is there a way to change this behavior--preferably on a per-document basis, but even via an obscure setting somewhere?**

(In Windows, Adobe Acrobat displays the pages "correctly". I realize I could just download Adobe Acrobat for Mac, but I'm curious if this can be done in Preview.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is add a blank page next to the first page of the document. So it shifts all pages. Use it from `Edit` > `Insert Blank Page`.